# Netbeans build error

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

Netbeans project BUILD SUCCESSFUL without using java library but set library and try to build.
Display

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
```

Any one know how to solve this?

```
        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {
            String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
           Class.forName(driverName);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic43819.html

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to the included library was compiled lower version of java. i.e you are using java 1.7 and it's compiled in java 1.6